# Constraints vs Boundary Conditions

Tags: classical-mechanics, field-theory, boundary-conditions, causality

I have a very broad question about how the mathematical framework that classical theories of physics utilize to solve problems.

The question is: What are the intrinsic differences between the constraints utilized in "second wave" mechanics such as Lagrangian, Hamilton, Hamilton/Jacobi mechanics, and the boundary conditions we use when doing "potential theory" physics such as Thermodynamics, Classical Electrodynamics, early Quantum Theory, etc.?

For example, an early student of physics when exposed to a more advanced question in Mechanics may automatically start that problem by assuming motion brought on by some PDE like the wave equation, laplace/poisson equation, whereas a more advanced student will likely go straight to formulating the Lagrangian. One will look for boundary/initial conditions, the other will write a constraint equation. They will both use them to make their starting solution more specific to the problem in front of them.

I guess it has never been pointed out to me how one approach might be better than the other. Is it just that the differential equations from the lagrangian method lead to the starting point of the weaker student (heat,wave,laplace equations) and therefore makes them more robust? In all my analytical mechanics courses you usually never solve past a certain point. But all my Newtonian mechanics courses ask for real values at real times.

Another example, Vibrations on a circularly suspended thin film are pretty easily described by the wave equation (helmoltz equation maybe), but vibrations on a soap bubble suspended in air is a nightmare to understand. The difference in my mind between these is that the first one has obvious boundary conditions, and but the latter really doesn't. You can however, set a volume constraint pretty simply.

So again my question: How does the act of setting up boundary conditions, relate to the act of setting up constraint equations?

Any insight would be appreciated,

Comment: Sounds like OP is essentially describing the difference between [elliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_boundary_value_problem) & [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) problems.